# C# run-time NullReferenceException when calling method

Tags: c#, class, nullreferenceexception

A newbie to C# here (more C++ for many years) struggling with perhaps a simple problem, but unable to diagnose.

**Class definition:**

```
public class myClass{
String prop1, prop2,... propn;
public void setValues(String input){
prop1 = input.Substring(1,5);
prop2 = input.Substring(6,10);
...
propn = input.Substring((n-1)*5+1,n*5));
}
public getProp1() {return prop1;}
public getProp2() {return prop2;}
...
public getPropn() {return propn;}
}
```

**In program**

```
    myClass[] Entries = new myClass[50];
    int i=0;
    String Line
    while(i<=49){
    Line = inputFile.ReadLine(); //<--System.NullReferenceException thrown here at run-time
    Entries[i++].setValues(Line);
    }
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated to figure out this run-time exception.  I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and this is a console application...if that's relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exception is actually at the line below, i.e. Entries[i++].setValues(Line);

Comment: where's your `inputFile` defined?

Comment: Thanks AStopher.  That was helpful to figure out that the class itself was apparently null, even though I have a constructor that initializes all properties.  [perhaps an extension to the original post but...] shouldn't the constructor execute upon creation of the array of classes, and each instance of the class be initialized?

Comment: Hi Sten.  The input file is defined earlier in my code using StreamReader.  I can confirm that it's opening and the "Line" value shows correct in watch.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 myClass[] Entries = new myClass[50];
```

Creates an array filled with `null`'s for values. So `Entries[i++]` will return you a `null` resulting in the error in your question. You can create an object of your type with `new` for example like this:

```
while(i<=49)
{
    Line = inputFile.ReadLine(); 
    var instance  = new myClass();
    instance.setValues(Line); 
    Entries[i++] = instance ;
}
```